# Deciphering Irish Locations & Names (1873 Marriage License)

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, ireland, 1870s

I have a marriage record from Burt County Nebraska for my Great Great Grandfather.  I'm having trouble with the handwriting, and would appreciate any help in deciphering it.  Specifically, I know from other sources that the groom was born "near Tralee, County Kerry, Ireland".  Can anybody make out the actual location written on this document?

[image: snippet from 1873 marriage docment]

I am also finding it difficult trying to decipher the mothers' maiden names.  First names appear to be Ellen and Jane.  But the last names aren't coming together for me.  Thoughts?

[image]

The full document is [available for download here](http://www.pmkelly.com/2010/08/kelly-evans-marriage-1873/) if anyone wants a closer look at it.  (The link for the full document is at the bottom of the page.)

Comment: At first sight, the maiden surnames look like Corvin and Kilda.

Comment: @AndyW - Thanks!  My first crack at them were always Corvain and Kilda.  Neither resulted in any new results.  I'll go back and make sure I've tried Corvin as well.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm wondering if the clerk might have mis-heard the name *Listowel*.   For pronunciations see https://forvo.com/word/listowel/

Wikipedia's article on [Listowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listowel) says:

> Listowel (/lɪsˈtoʊl/; Irish: Lios Tuathail, meaning "Tuathal's
>   ringfort") is a Heritage town and a market town in County Kerry,
>   Ireland, and is situated on the River Feale, 28 km (17 mi) from the
>   county town, Tralee.

For a map, see GENUKI's entry on [Tralee](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/irl/KER/Tralee) -- the Google map displayed on that page shows Listowel and Tralee.  On that page you can also see the names of other nearby towns and calculate the distance from Tralee to other places.

Resources for finding the names of places and townlands in Ireland:

- Wikipedia: [List of townlands of County Kerry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_townlands_of_County_Kerry)
- [County Kerry page](https://www.townlands.ie/kerry/) at [Irish Townlands](https://www.townlands.ie/)
- SWilson.Info's [Townland Index and Database - 1851](http://www.swilson.info/townlands.php)
- The Irish Genealogical Society's Guide to the [Index of Townlands, 1901](http://www.irishancestors.ie/?page_id=5392)
- [IreAtlas Townland database](http://www.thecore.com/seanruad/)
- Dublin City University's [Placenames Database of Ireland](https://www.logainm.ie/en/)
- [Irish Genealogy Toolkit](http://www.irish-genealogy-toolkit.com/)
- FamilySearch Wiki: [Ireland Gazetteers](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Ireland_Gazetteers)

Comment: Thank you!  You may well be onto something here.  And many thanks for the links... will be digging through these over the weekend!

Comment: There are other candidates, but I was trying to find something with the L coloring at the end of the word.

Answer (score 2):

I think Listowel is a good guess but based on that, then the maiden name may well be Garvin or Garvan. According to this site, incidence of that surname more likely in Cork area (based on 1901 census). County Cork borders Kerry (Listowel) area than Corvin: https://www.johngrenham.com/findasurname.php?surname=Garvin

Comment: Thank you!  Will definitely make a note of this and give that website a look.  Much appreciated!

Comment: You're very welcome Patrick - best of luck with your research